# Some Rebuses for U

Tags: rebus, knowledge

Here are some rebuses all about **U**!

The first is very easy, the second is moderate (you may need to think a bit on this one) and the last is moderate-hard (it is taken much, much further than the rest, probably too far for some), and is a name of 5 letters.

[image: Rebuses for U]

<sub>All images constructed with U's, except for any rectangles.</sub>

#### Hints for rebus 3

1.

> The red circle could have been replaced with an arrow pointing to the UU, but there wasn't enough room and it was hard to make out of U's.

2.

> For the first 'step' think along the lines of:
>  [image: Secrets]

3.

> Keep in mind the list notation (1., 2., 3., ...) when you apply Hint #2.

4.

> The first part involves doing the same thing as Rebus #2.

5.

> You need to interpret 'U' in a different sense to those that have already been used.

6.

> In a race, the number one person comes _____. In a list, the number one item comes _____.

7.

> If {2,to,too}, {U,you,___}?

---

Please post interpretations of rebus 3 even if they don't make a phrase or anything, I'll tell you if you're on the right track (there are multiple steps!)

If you want more hints, I've been progressively hinting a bit on Neil W's post too, so look there.

---

**EDIT: I intended to put *'and is a name of 5 letters'* in the original puzzle at post time but I forgot about it, so sorry to those who tried and couldn't get it.**

---

With thanks to ?? for part of the last clue:

> David Astle

Comment: Keep talking...

Comment: Regarding hint #6: in computing, the list item with index 1 is usually the second item in the list.

Comment: I do program, so I realise it. However, hint 6 is an analogy more than a literal translation. @Samthere

Comment: @boboquack Ah, I was commenting as an interpretation in case it helped other solvers! Seems I'm on the wrong track :D

Comment: Don't tell me DA is involved, no wonder I've got no idea.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1:

> U in the form of a London Underground (tube) sign = YouTube

2:

> Spider + double u, double u, double u = spider web

3: (1st attempt)

> Double u = w, inner (inside the red circle) = winner = first in results

3: fishing...

> So maybe Us = use, first use, high use, over use???

3. Getting silly...

> I can't work it out, so just like **U2**'s **number one** hit,  *I Still Haven't Found What I'm Looking For*, too easy!

3. Then maybe...

> Okay if it's first double u, then maybe W stands for woman, the first woman, mythologically speaking, was *Eve*

Comment: You are good at these :) +1

Comment: Good work with the first two! Unfortunately the third one needs a bit more work. I'll post a hint that might help you a bit.

Comment: Your 'first use' was the closest. But put that together with 'double u' to get the first 'step' in this rebus.

Comment: W does not stand for anything. But what could U be if not a letter or you?

Comment: Ewe. But that doesn't help.

Comment: Or yew, if it is a homophone, which doesn't help either.

Comment: @TheGreatEscaper Doesn't it? What could a double-ewe be?

Answer (score 6):

First

> Already solved by Neil W as **YOUTUBE**

Second

> Already solved by Neil W as **SPIDER WEB**

Third

> **DOLLY** The final hint shows homophone of U is used, which is EWE. @SP3000 identified the right answer in TSL as [Dolly Sheep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dolly_(sheep)). First + Female Sheep Cloned(Ewe = Female Sheep and UU's = Clones) = The sheep was the first mammal cloned.

Comment: Note that the hint didn't have numbering on the side...

Comment: @boboquack Added another attempt

Comment: For clarity, yes, your most recent attempt was the answer. I must have not seen it, so sorry.

Answer (score 3):

Very partial, but the 1 makes me think to

> the [London Underground](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/London_Underground), aka the tube. The logo is almost the same as in the image.

Answer (score 2):

Guessing 1-

> "You have been blocked" - U on block rectangle , outer circle like a signal

Guessing 2-

> "insects ate you" -because ant and there are '8' U

Comment: You sure there are 8, not 6?

Answer (score 2):

For the third one:

> First in use  (1. -> First ; UU -> U's -> Use  ;  U's are inside so its "in use")

Another try:

> First win (1. -> First  UU -> Double U -> W and W is in the two U or arrows as per hint).

Answer (score 2):

I'm thinking the third rebus might be:

> World War I

or

> First 'W' - or the word 'world' in world wide web.

It might be something like

> The top/first www, which in turn could refer to a visitor rank in websites. So, it might also be www.Google.com.

Answer (score 1):

1. Is:

   > U turn? As the U is turned on itself

Comment: No, there is a bit more in the box than that... keep trying! :)

Answer (score 0):

For #3, Going by the thesaurus of [*you*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/you), is it:

> **Youse?**
>  Based on Neil W's findings, eve pronounces as yew and based on it, the first one would be Y and O (O is the circle) and then U and then S (Changing the position can be seen as S) and then E (Changing the positions).

I might be thinking too much though... :P

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts on the third one, which remains unsolved after more than a year. (I regret that I still haven't solved it.) First of all,

> it seems clear from the hints that the first-in-list position is meant to signify TOP.

Then

> OP's comments on Neil's answer appear to tell us that we should be reading these Us as "ewes".

Finally,

> we are told that the answer is a 5-letter name, and I take the "too far for some" comment to mean that there's more "indirection" in this than is usual in a rebus.

So

> what would two ewes be? A very small FLOCK, perhaps. I've seen the term FLOCK TOP used to mean either an upper garment or the upper surface of a table made of "flocking". But that's not a five-letter name. There is at least one wool shop called Two Ewes, but that doesn't help me. You might wish someone, on the anniversary of their birth, "Hippo birdie two ewes" or some variation on that theme, but again I don't see how that gets us anywhere near a five-letter name. We could turn "ewes" into "sheep", but "top sheep" and "sheep top" don't seem helpful. Likewise "lambs". I don't think there's any special term for the top of a sheep. (Its back? Its head?) A ewes' top might be a WOOLLY JUMPER but that's far from being a five-letter name. Five letters seems awfully little space.

At this point I'm stuck. Perhaps the name is of someone I've never heard of and the above will enable someone to make the final leap. Or, you know, not.